# Azure Devops Release pipeline unable to take latest C# version

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a console application which has async calls for e.g. the signature of the main method looks like this

```
static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
{

}
```

I am able to compile the build in my local machine. But I have a **VSTS (DevOps Azure) CI/CD** pipeline where I am using a custom hosted agent in that machine, over there once the CI executes it gives the error:

> ##[error]CSC(0,0): Error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Comment: "I am using a custom hosted agent in that machine". That's not enough. Remember on your machine there can be multiple MSBuild instances, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-rough-history-of-msbuild-cc72a217fa98 Your pipeline definition must point to the latest MSBuild instace, so as to use the latest C# compiler.

Answer (score 5):

I got it working by forcing the user agent to use VS2017.
Click phase 1 and then change it to the following:
[HostedVS2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQ6Wp.png)

This forces the user agent to use 2017 which has the latest version of C# instead of 2015 (which it was falling back to for me).

Comment: This did it for me. Various threads on various sites were saying "set the langver property", but none of that worked. This did! Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Can you try building your local code in release mode and see if you are getting the same issue.

Make sure to add C# 7.1 to any CPU and release property groups.

- Right-click Your Project, click Properties
- Click Build if it's not already selected
- Change Configuration to All Configurations
- Click Advanced...
- Change the language version

Refer this issue in github for more details.

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/21783

Answer (score 3):

https://www.visualstudiogeeks.com/azure/devops/using-latest-version-of-csharp-with-dotnetcore

in pipeline
in visual studio build
add to MSBuild Arguments

> /property:langversion=latest

or

Edit the c# Project and add

> `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>`

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PackageAction>BuildDefault</PackageAction>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PackageAction>BuildDefault</PackageAction>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```